# Simulink navigation too slow with sliders and knobs

Tags: matlab, graphics, simulink

Is there any graphics option in Simulink that can be tuned to have a smoother navigation of the model?

I'm working on a Simulink model using knobs and sliders to give inputs to some variables. With these elements, the navigation of the model becomes incredibly slow. Without them, I can explore the model very smoothly.  Currently, I'm only using 6 knobs, but I have tested various configurations on various different models.

[image: Capture of knobs in current model that make navigation slow and]

I'm confident MATLAB is doing something with the graphics which slow down the visualization. I don't see how my computer's hardware wouldn't handle the update of few simple figures:

- Processor: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v2 @ 2.1GHz 2.1GHz
- RAM: 28 GB
- OS: Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bit

Here follows the valuable rating of my system performed by Microsoft (scaled from a minimum of 1.0 to a maximum of 7.9)
[image: System rating]

Comment: Can you describe the specificaations of your computer? My crappy laptop runs million element EM-3DFEMs easily. And its a crappy laptop.

Comment: @AnderBiguri: done. I'm sure there must be a tickable option somewhere in MATLAB/Simulink's options to have it go smoother

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathwork's support engineers indicated there is currently no way to improve the navigation smoothness.